# How to prove it using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ defination of limit?

Tags: limits

**The question is** :

Show that,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin \frac {1} {x}} {\sin \frac {1} {x}}$$ does not exist.

How to solve it by the defination of limit? Can it be solved using sequential criterion? Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the limit really not exist?  Doesn't the expression equal $1$ for all non-zero $x$?

Comment: That limit is 1.

Comment: We should qualify that we must have $x$ such that $\sin(1/x) \neq 0$.  Otherwise, the ratio is undefined.  But, for every sequence $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots$, that increases without bound and satisfies $\sin(1/x_{k}) \neq 0$, the limit of your ratio will be $1$ as $k \rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: But in my book it is given that the limit does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure @avs , about  the case x=0 , because it is the same curve so it should have the same value for all x even at x=0.

Comment: What will happen if $sin \frac {1} {x} = 0$?

Comment: it will still be 1 because it is the same curve.

Comment: The case $x=0$ does not bother me as much as the case $x = 1 / \pi$, which turns the ratio into the indeterminacy $0/0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, but the claim is wrong.  So I will provide an $\varepsilon-\delta$ that the claim is wrong.  More specifically, I will show that 
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {sin \frac {1} {x}} {sin \frac {1} {x}}=1$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, put $\delta=\varepsilon$. Then whenever $0<|x-0|<\delta$ (and $1\neq x\pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$), we have 
$$\left| \frac {sin \frac {1} {x}} {sin \frac {1} {x}} -1\right|=0<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: In fact $x = \frac {1} {{\pie}{k}}$ does not belong to the domain of defination of the given function, for any $k \in \mathbb {Z}$. Isn't it?

Comment: That's true.  You could replace "for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$" in my answer with "for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$"

Comment: Sorry for my wrong claim. My book misguides me badly.

Comment: No apologies are necessary.  I would recommend that you double check the claims in your book, now that you've found some errors.  This wouldn't be the first time a book had an error in it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and $x\ne0$, $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sin \frac {1} {x}} {\sin \frac {1} {x}} =1$$ since it became a constant function!

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be an abbreviation for $(\sin 1/x)/\sin 1/x .$ The statement $$\forall e>0\;\exists d>0\;\forall x \;(|x|<d\implies |f(x)-1|<e)$$ is FALSE. Because for any $d>0$ there exists $x\in (-d,d)$ at which $f(x)$ does not exist :

Given $d>0$ : For any large enough $n\in \mathbb Z^+$ we have $0<1/\pi n <d $, so if $x=1/\pi n$ then $x\in (-d,d) ,$ and $\sin 1/x=0$ so the formal expression $(\sin 1/x)/\sin 1/x$ is $0/0.$

Comment: Your statement is false.  It should be $\forall e>0\;\exists d>0\;\forall x\in\textrm{Dom}(f) \;(|x|<d\implies |f(x)-1|<e)$.  We need to take the domain into account

Comment: The Q does not specify that x is restricted to any particular proper subset of R. That is precisely the point of the Q.